# How can we create a redux store in DvaJs?

Tags: redux, react-redux, dvajs

I have a project with umi and dva and I can't create a global store... 
My project is based on this template: https://ant.design/docs/react/practical-projects

Answer (score 0):

Newest documents but hasn't been translated yet: https://umijs.org/plugins/plugin-dva

---

Create global model files in folder `src/models`.
If a model file defined an effective model, it can be listed by running command `umi dva list model`.